# How to overlay an image with text which comes from the URL?

Tags: php, image-processing

To begin let me summary the situation:

We currently run a reward system for a local retailer, at the moment the vouchers which are emailed out to customers are a simple PNG file which can be printed and returned to the store for a promotional discount.

We would like to overlay the customers member number and name onto the voucher when they click a link which is sent to their email address. Our email system allows us to personalise the link which each customer receives.

For example at the moment the customer receives the following link: www.website.com/testvoucher.htm

Now from some limited experience of the matter I understand it would be possible to use php to overlay the voucher image to create personlised vouchers. I imagine the link would become something like this:

www.website.com/testvoucher.php?membernumber='2100000'&membername='Mrs%20Smith'

My question is using php if possible how can I create an image which is personalised from the URL?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to look into the [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) API. More specifically the `annotateImage` function described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php).

```
<?php
    /* Create some objects */
    $image = new Imagick();
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

    /* New image */
    $image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

    /* Black text */
    $draw->setFillColor('black');

    /* Font properties */
    $draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
    $draw->setFontSize( 30 );

    /* Create text */
    $image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

    /* Give image a format */
    $image->setImageFormat('png');

    /* Output the image with headers */
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    echo $image;
?>
```

(*copy pasted from the function documentation page*)

You can simply email them with a link to `www.website.com/testvoucher.php?membernumber=2100000&membername=Mrs%20Smith` where resides the above php code slightly modified to use the voucher image and get the text from the url.

Comment: @JackNaylor Also, to go extra fancy you can put the image in the email by using `img` tag with the `src` attribute with the url format discussed. Another thing to keep in mind is that the reason I went for ImageMagick is that everyone is saying that it has more options and better performance than its counterpart GD which is a early fork of ImageMagick.

Comment: Thanks for all your help I now have this working as required. I used both answers to find what I needed. Also the email tip was very helpful.

Comment: @JackNaylor No problem, just keep in mind that if you do the php source for image trick you'll want to make sure you're using the proper headers `header('Content-type: image/png');`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GD Image library for that :

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

You can use several functions to open the image according their extensions for eg. :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php for JPEG

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php for PNG

Also you can get the name by `$_GET['membername']` and print it on image using :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php